# Multiple Asynchronous query chaining

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, project-server

I have a Sharepoint 2013 application that has multiple (3) ExecuteQueryAsync calls in 3 different functions.

Two of them are referring to the Project Server project context, and one is referring to the Sharepoint client context.

I managed to nest the two querys that are used with the project context, and they are working together without any problems.

The problem is, that before this could happen, I need to access a remote domain for some information and I have a **crossDomainCall**.

This crossDomainCall has an ExecuteQueryAsync to the Sharepoint Client Context,

It goes through it, but if I want to run the other two querys after that, those will give back this error message : **Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '404'. The status text of response is 'Not found'.**

This is the crossDomainCall

```
sampleclass.prototype.crossDomainCall = function (SPHostUrl, callUrl, successCallback, failureCallback) {

    $.getScript(SPHostUrl + "/_layouts/15/" + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", Function.createDelegate(this, function () {

    // First construct our JSOM request
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var crossDomainRequest = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    alert(crossDomainRequest);
    crossDomainRequest.set_url(callUrl);
    crossDomainRequest.set_method("GET");

    var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(clientContext, crossDomainRequest);

    // Execute our request with a callback function
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var statusCode = response.get_statusCode();

        // HTTP status success / failure determines which callback function to send our results to
        if (statusCode === 200) {
            // JavaScript functions are first-class objects (how cool!)
            successCallback(response.get_body());
        }
        else {
            failureCallback(statusCode, response.get_body());
        }
    }));
}));
};
```

It feels to me, that the second and third Async querys are not able to get the correct URL, after this one goes through.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, got it to work!
I used project context for every ExecuteQueryAsync so there's no mixup now.